# GitHub Action (CI/CD)

Tags: c#, linux, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to download a file using Selenium with chromedriver and C#. My code works perfectly with Windows OS, but when I try to execute the same code on GitHub Action in Linux, everythings fine, no erros, all elements are found but no file downloaded in the specific directory? I am using the code below, any idea ?

Among them, I changed the default download folder to the folder I specified, and set it with an absolute path, but there is no file under this folder

```
var option = new ChromeOptions();
string downloadsFolderPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "Downloads");
option.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", downloadsFolderPath);
```